# How do I get a message in a div box instead of the alert box with ajax success?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create error validation handling for my custom form. What I want to do is get the error messages in a div instead of the browser alert box but I'm new to all of this and have no idea how to do it. I tried to do some research but found nothing useful for my case.

Basically my form works and shows error or success messages correctly, but I don't want to display them in the alert box, but in a dedicated div. Thanks for any answers, I appreciate any help.

So here's what I have:

**My section which contains all the various messages error**

```
<div class="error-message-wrapper">
   <!-- Here are all my error messages that are printed with the wc_print_notices(); function -->
</div>
```

**My Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 

    //Ajax function
    jQuery.ajax({
      
      type: "post",
      data: jQuery(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
      url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      success : function( response ) {
        alert( response );
      }

    });
    });
});
```

**My function**

```
function save_account_details() {

  if (trim($_POST['account_first_name']) == '') {
    $msg = wc_print_notices();
    $response = $msg;
  } else {
    $response = "Settings Saved!";
  }

  // Don't forget to exit at the end of processing
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit();

}
```

Comment: You can replace/inject contents by getting div element by ID?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I appreciate it. I could do it, but with the class instead of the ID and I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u wanna show in exist class then choose element by document.querySelector(".className").innerHtml = response.textFromResponse or u can do like below

```
 Query(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 

    //Ajax function
    jQuery.ajax({
      
      type: "post",
      data: jQuery(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
      url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      success : function( response ) {
        alert( response );
        const uiDivElement = document.createElement("DIV");
        uiDivElement.innerHTML = response.textFromResponse
        document.appendChild(uiDivElement)
      }

    });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your suggestions but I keep seeing the messages in the browser alert box instead of in the div. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: i didnt remove alert message from code u can remove it from code that one " alert( response )  "

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. It didn't work directly but it helped achieve this that is working for me: `jQuery('.woocommerce-notices-wrapper').append(response);`